# Rosjava: Problem sending a string to the sample

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I am playing around with the rosjava tutorial. When running the Listener node together with the talker node it works fine and the Hello world is printed out. But if I run

```
rostopic pub /chatter std_msgs/String "Hello"
```

It will not work anymore. The listener throws the following exceptions:

```
01.02.2012 14:52:15 org.ros.internal.node.topic.UpdatePublisherRunnable run
SCHWERWIEGEND: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
01.02.2012 14:52:17 org.ros.internal.node.topic.UpdatePublisherRunnable run
SCHWERWIEGEND: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: Connection exception:   eich-ThinkPad/192.168.103.42:39099
01.02.2012 14:52:17 org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler exceptionCaught
SCHWERWIEGEND: Channel exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
01.02.2012 14:52:17 org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler exceptionCaught
SCHWERWIEGEND: Channel exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12835/rosjava:-problem-sending-a-string-to-the-sample/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved the issue temporarily be setting ROS_IP to 127.0.0.1. How can I tell the Listener Sample node to use the external IP of my machine? Is the Listerner Sample node bound to localhost?

---

Originally posted by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) with karma: 202 on 2012-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-02-14**:
Something is wrong with your network configuration. You shouldn't get a "no route to host" exception when trying to connect to your own external IP.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-02-23**:
Have you tried setting ROS_IP to your external IP? 192.168.103.42 in your example log output.